# Image tag not working in react while sending image path from rails backend

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, reactjs

This is what I did in the frontend for sending an image file.

```
handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    const { organization } = this.state
    let reader = new FileReader()
    let file = event.target.files[0]
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.setState({
        organization: {
          ...organization,
          logo: file,
          logoFile: reader.result
        }
      })
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
}

<input type="file"
     name="logo"
     onChange={this.handleFileChange} />
```

This is what I did in rails OrganizationsController to save the image in a database.

```
org = Organization.new(org_params)
org.logo = params[:organization][:logo].tempfile.path
if org.save
   render json: org
end
```

Here is the code for organization.rb model

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :logoFile, LogoUploader
  validates :name, logo, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true  
end
```

While extracting the path of an image from the backend I got the following path:

```
<img alt="" height='35px' width='37px' src="/var/folders/k3/k69tmr710wj_2vstx3rz01l80000gn/T/RackMultipart20180523-1093-1y543vo.png" />
```

With this image path, the image is not displaying in my app. But when I paste this path in my browser, it displays the image with this path:

```
file:///var/folders/k3/k69tmr710wj_2vstx3rz01l80000gn/T/RackMultipart20180523-1093-1y543vo.png
```

Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: I think the `gem 'carrierwave'` will definitely come in handy for you because it will help to manage all these manipulations behind scenes.

Comment: @Saraswati Saud Recently i have given the same answer, and i have given asnwer below as well as you can see. Actually what happens with react thats its sending back Actionpatch dispatcher so here by you would have to convert it into physical file, before save it. for more details check back my answer, let me know for further guidance .

Comment: @Saraswati Saud Could you please let me know , if the issue still there or any further guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `params[:organization][:logo].tempfile.path` you are getting the temporary path of the file before it is uploaded and saved somewhere in your system so you need to upload the image and then get the path of the image and then do

```
org.logo = uploaded_image_path
```

You can use existing gem solutions like [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to handle the file uploading logic.

You should have an uploader class for logo like,

```
class LogoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
end
```

You need to use the uploader class in your controller to upload the image,

```
uploader = LogoUploader.new

uploader.store!(params[:your_file])
```

I'm using examples from the carrierwave github page and it should work without much hassle for you.

Comment: Yes, I used carrierwave gem and the image is not saved in public/upload/directory. What should I do?

Comment: Show your org model and controller code where you upload the image

Comment: @SaraswatiSaud Your image is not being saved at backed properly, that is why you are not getting exactly image path. i will advise you to check params before save it at backed.

Answer (score 2):

```
  def get_image
    unless params[:file].blank?
      uploaded_io = params[:file]
      path = Rails.root.join("public/system/temp_files/images", uploaded_io.original_filename)
      File.open(path, 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(uploaded_io.read)
      end
      return path.to_s
    end
  end
```

At you method: -

```
    org = Organization.new(org_params)
    image_path = get_image
    org.logo = Rails.root.join('public', image_path.split('/public/')[1]).open)
   if org.save
     File.delete(image_path)
     render json: org
   end
```

Explanation: -

1- First you must need to create physical file to save it in your db, so here i have created a temporary file in project's public directory.

2- Just write this file using temporary file path to your database. and after that delete this temporary physical file

Comment: are paperclip and carrierwave the same thing? I don't think OP is using paperclip

Comment: @Subash Its not the things about paperclip or carrierwave the concept is to the convert aciondispatcher into physical file before save it into database. and the concept will remain same for both gem. i forgot to mention that this temporary file should be deleted after save it.

Comment: Yes, thats why its helpful for OP to explain using the tool they are using,  OP looks like a beginner so its better to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: @Gabbar - `image_path = get_image.tempfile.path` while adding this line, it shows error `undefined method tempfile for this path`. Now, what shall I do?

Comment: @SaraswatiSaud ohh sorry its just only `image_path = get_image`. not 
`image_path = get_image.tempfile.path`, updated answer.

Comment: The same problem exists again. Cannot display image in the app but displayed in browser

Comment: @SaraswatiSaud are you using image_tag or img scr html tag

Comment: @SaraswatiSaud could you try convert image path into `assets_url(path_of_image)` ?